# Format Google Analytics Date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, date, microsoft-excel, excel-online

I'm using the following formula to retrieve week day and day from a Google Analytics report in Google Spreadsheet:

```
=CONCATENATE(CHOOSE(WEEKDAY('90diaspessoas'!A16),"Domingo","Segunda","Terça","Quarta","Quinta","Sexta","Sábado")," ",TO_TEXT('90diaspessoas'!A16 ) )
```

It returns to me a value like this:

```
Sábado 2017-12-02
```

Where `Sábado` means `Saturday`, the problem is that the date is being displayed with this format `YYYY-MM-DD` and I need it to display like this `DD-MM-YYYY`, I tried using the following but it didn't work:

```
=CONCATENATE(CHOOSE(WEEKDAY('90diaspessoas'!A16),"Domingo","Segunda","Terça","Quarta","Quinta","Sexta","Sábado")," ",TO_TEXT(DATE(LEFT('90diaspessoas'!B16,4),MID('90diaspessoas'!B16,5,2),RIGHT('90diaspessoas'!B16,2)) ))
```

This is what I'm getting: `Sábado 12/31/2030`

The table:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use TEXT, instead of TO_TEXT:

```
=TEXT('90diaspessoas'!A16,"dd-mm-yyyy" )
```

As long as underlying date number is correct, This will work.

OR

Set formatting in '90diaspessoas'!A16  correctly to  DD-MM-YYYY. Then,  TO_TEXT will work.

**FINAL CONCATENATED FORMULA:**

```
=TEXT('90diaspessoas'!A16,"dddd dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Can you explain me how did you manage to join both data without using CONCATENATE term?

Comment: Wait, there is a problem here. It's in English. I need it to be in Portuguese...

Comment: Can I use it like this instead? `=CONCATENATE(CHOOSE(WEEKDAY('90diaspessoas'!A16),"Domingo","Segunda","Terça","Quarta","Quinta","Sexta","Sábado")," ",TEXT('90diaspessoas'!A16,"dd-mm-yyyy"))`

Comment: Did what you suggested, but had to change language too and make functions appear in Portuguese. Had to revert, I'm afraid that if I leave the functions in Portuguese, everything may end up messed up..

Comment: Wait, looks like it was a cache thing. Changing the locale solved. thx